# Handling post request in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a form directly in a material. I have to send results form values via email to admin and in parallel put them into db. I have a code for all things in my handler.php. The question is where should I put my handler.php and how should I provide a link in action field of the form?

I tried this aproach of url:  `action="<?php echo JURI::base( true ).'/modules/mod_form_handler/handler.php; ?>"` , hence my handler.php was put into `/modules/mod_form_handler/`directory, but result after submission was "404"

PS. I am oldshool programmer, so plz do not judge me for avoiding extensions/plugins to solve the task, I just want to make it fast for me :)

Comment: Just don't use `action` attribute, and it will post well

Comment: @Mr.Alien Form declared <form class="form-validate" action="<?php echo JURI::base( true ).'/modules/mod_form_handler/handler.php; ?>" method="post">, action provides my url, how can I avoid it?

Comment: A component is not needed at all. It can be achieved using only your module. There are form modules that send simple emails to the specified e-mail address, so if that is possible, all that would need to be done is adding in the functionality to insert data into the database.

Answer (score -1):

Joomla doesn't allow to submit form data to module. You have to submit form action in any of your component.

Comment: can you provide example?

Comment: you can submit your form on one of your controller like com_mycomponent. & your action will be index.php?com_mycomponent&task=form handler. In com_mycomponents controller add function form handler() & do what you want. Thats it.

Answer (score -2):

If you need a 'quick and dirty' solution, you're sadly out of luck. At the very least you will need a component, with a controller whose method you can invoke from your module's form (&task=subcontroller.methodname i.e. &task=contacts.save).

To get going quickly, just go to component-creator.com and create a simple component with one table (where you will be storing the data) - it's a free service!, and you will get a nice basic component with a subcontroller method "save" so you can route there from your module with &task=subcontroller.save

You will need to make sure other required fields are inserted in your module i.e. the token.

Comment: Please make sure you explain why you downvote so we can all learn something